# Echo an Array through $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, include

So I'm fairly new to php, and I've been trying to search for the solution to my problem for a while; I've found other posts that are similar, but have never found an answer that I understand enough to try.

The comments should explain what I want, but if it's a bit too vague, I'm sorry. I don't really know how to explain this.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

```
<?php include ("calc.php"); ?>

<form method="post" name="form">
<input type="text" name="username"/>
</form>

<form>
<input id="info" type="text" value="<?php echo $info[1]; //This just appears blank, and I don't know how to fix ?>"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"])) {
    calc($_POST["username"]); //Posts to calc.php where the function "calc" will put some info into an array called $info[1]
}
?>
```

Comment: I am not able to see any element which pass Array to php.Where do you want to assign Array and retrieve in php?

Comment: This is the **most vague** question I've read all year.  In fact, you haven't even asked a question.  The fact that you are new to PHP should have nothing to do with your ability to at least attempt to state what you are trying to do, and ask for suggestions on how to go about doing it.  Care to try again?

Answer (score 0):

Try change the order of instrucions, first add data in array, then access that data

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"])) {
 calc($_POST["username"]); //Posts to calc.php where the function "calc" will put some info into an array called $info[1]
}
?>
<form>
<input id="info" name="info" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($info[1])) echo $info[1]; ?>"/>
</form>
```